# do FILE throws exception when checking if file exists

Tags: perl

I am having problem understanding why the following code throws errors.

I have a simple script:

do_test.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

do 'test.pl';
warn 'error 1: ' . $@ if $@;
warn 'error 2: ' . $! if $!;
```

test.pl

```
use Path::Tiny;

path('anything')->exists;
```

I am not entirely clear why `test.pl` runs just fine and `do_test.pl` throws an error: `error 2: No such file or directory`

This is a simplified version of my code.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Note that in [recent docs for do](https://perldoc.pl/functions/do) it's clarified that you actually should do `do './test.pl';` (or preferably an absolute path) because it actually searches `@INC` similar to `require` otherwise. It is sadly impossible to tell the difference between a file that returns false and an error loading the file, so make sure your file returns a true value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$!` is only meaningful if an error occurred, so your code claims an error occurred when none did.

Change

```
use Path::Tiny;
path('anything')->exists;
```

to

```
use Path::Tiny;
path('anything')->exists;
1;
```

and change

```
do 'test.pl';
warn 'error 1: ' . $@ if $@;
warn 'error 2: ' . $! if $!;
```

to

```
do('test.pl')
   or die($@ || $!);
```

Comment: I actually found out the mistake myself but didn't update the question. Thanks for your time, will upvote this!